# Обработать ввод пользователя в консоли

Tags: c++, c, bash, input

Я знаю, что обработать ввод пользователя в консоли можно с помощью `getchar()` или `scanf()`. Но при таком методе есть минус - при нажатии клавиш вперед и назад, курсор не сдвигается, а появляются новые символы. Например в BASH, такого нет. Как это сделано?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Там используется библиотека `libreadline`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <readline/history.h>

int main()
{
    printf( "%s\n", readline( "test> " ) );
    return 0;
}
```

Сборка и запуск:

```
$ gcc -o readliner -lreadline -lncurses readliner.c
$ ./readliner
test>
```

readline позволяет выполнять не только такие простейшие операции как сдвиг курсора, но огромнейшее множество других:

- история;
- автопродолжение (autocompletion);
- работа с блоками строки;

и многие-многие другие.

Подробнее о GNU Readline:

- [Programming with GNU Readline](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/readline/rlman_23.html) (англ.)

В UNIX/Linux (в первую очередь в GNU/Linux) системах readline является фактически стандартом для выполнения интерактивного ввода информации, однако существуют и альтернативы. Я бы особо выделил две:

- [Editline](http://thrysoee.dk/editline/) так же исзвестная как *libedit*;
- https://github.com/antirez/linenoise

Обе эти библиотеки отличаются от readline простотой, легковесностью и имеют в противоположность ей BSD-лицензию.

Comment: @egor: В общем случае для таких вещей вам надо отказаться от `stdio` и использовать системно-зависимые библиотеки (`readline` — одна из них).

Comment: @VladD: readline является фактически стандартом на организацию интерактивного ввода данных в GNU/Linux, подавляющее большинство программ используют именно эту библиотеку, хотя верно и то, что есть и другие библиотеки, решающие сходные задачи

Comment: Это да, readline по сути стандарт. Но на декстопе существуют и другие операционки. :) Плюс представьте себе ситуацию, когда вы вовсе не хотите вводить строку, а хотите сделать [WASD-управление](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WASD), как для игр. (Думаю, readline с этим не справится.)

Comment: Вау! Спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 3):

Во многих программах разработчики для организации редактируемого ввода используют готовую библиотеку [Readline](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline) или её аналоги. Она кроме перемещения курсора умеет даже выполнять автодополнение вводимого текста.

Работает эта библиотека следующим образом.

Терминал — программа, которая отвечает за отображение информации и её ввод, — может не только принимать текст от программы, который нужно отобразить, но и специальные коды. Фактически, терминал — это управляемая «прослойка» между программой и клавиатурой/экраном.

Например, код `\n` переводит курсор в следующую строку, а `\r` перемещает в начало строки (не стирая её). Существуют и другие [коды](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_ANSI). С их помощью можно не только перемещать курсор, но и, например, [менять цвет текста](http://www.opennet.ru/base/dev/console_ctl.txt.html). ([Более полный список кодов на английском.](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm), посмотрите также `man console_codes`) Эти коды [стандартизированы](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-048.pdf) и будут более-менее одинаково работать на разных терминалах.

Скажем, команда

```
printf("AB\033[1DCD\n");
```

выведет на экран

> ACD

так как после символа `B` стоит управляющая последовательность `\033[1D`, смещающая курсор на одну позицию влево. Следующие символы (`CD`) будут печататься уже «поверх» буквы `B`.

Терминал может работать в разных режимах. В так называемом каноническом режиме вводимые данные обрабатываются как последовательность строк. Данные передаются программе только когда будет нажата клавиша Enter, а до тех пор вводом управляет сам терминал. В неканоническом режиме программа получает больший контроль над вводом и выводом, так как терминал уже не занимается вводом и выводом и передаёт каждый символ программе. Она в свою очередь может анализировать, какая клавиша была нажата и выводить текст, перемещать курсор, выполнять какие-то ещё действия.

Как именно управлять терминалом, как организовать управление — очень обширная тема для одного вопроса. Подробности вы можете найти, например, в книге Стивенса и Раго «UNIX. Профессиональное программирование».